# database Name in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Database dbMain where I keep record of Multiple Database

`dbMain(database) - > tblMain(table)`

`ID , DatabaseName , TableName`

- 1 , Db1 , tblMember
- 2, Db2, tblMember
- 3, Db3, tblMember

Now i want to run a query which will give the Admin detail

`(tblmember table -> UserType columnName )`

can someone suggest me how to write query which will tabke dbname + tablename from column and perform the specific task

Thanks

Comment: What kind of specific task?

Comment: Now i want to run a query which will give the Admin detail from all database

Comment: Are you wanting to get the columns from the table contained in tblmember? It is kind of unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: If I am guessing correctly you have a table with some stored proc names and database stored in a table. Now you want to execute these procs against the correct database? This design is atrocious and fraught with all sort of challenges. The only way to do this is with dynamic sql.

Comment: thanks @SeanLange dynamic sql solved my problem..